# List manipulation, averaging over lists and fidelity

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create vectors from a function `poly[α_, β_, δ_, ϕ1_]` were several variables (α, β, δ) are randomly sampled from a unit sphere. Then I want to vary another parameter of the function (ϕ1) over a specific range.

So I will end up with many vectors from `poly[α, β, δ, ϕ1]`. I want to find the fidelity (modulus of the inner product of two vectors squared) of the function `poly[α, β, δ, ϕ1]` with `poly[α, β, -δ, 0]` for each of these vectors.

Then I want to average the fidelity for each different instance of ϕ1.

So I can create a graph Δϕ1 vs Fidelity

So far I believe that I have gotten 80% of the way there, I have created the random input states and varied over ϕ1, but I am struggling in list manipulation to find the fidelities and average over them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Function:

```
poly[α_, β_, δ_, ϕ1_] := { α (Cos[theta1] Cos[theta2] Cos[theta3] - 
 Sin[theta1] Sin[theta3]), β E^(I ϕ1) (-Cos[theta1] Cos[theta2]^2 Cos[theta3] + Cos[theta1] Cos[theta3] Sin[theta2]^2 + 
 Cos[theta2] Sin[theta1] Sin[theta3]), δ E^(2 I ϕ1) ( 
Cos[theta1] Cos[theta2]^3 Cos[theta3] - 
 2 Cos[theta1] Cos[theta2] Cos[theta3] Sin[theta2]^2 - 
 Cos[theta2]^2 Sin[theta1] Sin[theta3])};

theta1 = -2.74889;
theta2 = -1.14372;
theta3 = 2.74889;
```

Calculate the random input states:

```
random = {};

n = 10; (*Number of input states for α, β, δ*)

Do[

 list = ({1, I}.#) & /@ 
   Partition[Normalize@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2 3], 2];

 α = list[[1]];
 β = list[[2]];
 δ = list[[3]];

 AppendTo[random, {list}];

 , {n}];

random;
```

Collect all α, β, δ terms in lists

```
cat = Flatten[random];
α = cat[[1 ;; All ;; 3]];
β = cat[[2 ;; All ;; 3]];  
δ = cat[[3 ;; All ;; 3]];
```

Vary ϕ1 to obtain various α, β, δ

```
start = 0;
end = 1;
increment = 1;
total = 1 + (end - start)/increment ;

offset = Flatten[Table[poly[α, β, δ, ϕ1], {ϕ1, start, end, increment}]] ;
```

Create an ideal list of α, β, δ with the same dimensions of `offset`:

```
ideal2 = Flatten[poly[α, β, -δ, 0]];
ideal3 = Flatten[Table[ideal2, total]];
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but you can shorten parts of your code quite a bit.  If you want to get a uniform sample of points in the unit sphere, a quicker way to do it would be `random = RandomPoint[Ball[], n] + I RandomPoint[Ball[], n];`  Then you can define `{α, β, δ} = Transpose[random]`

Comment: Please, just post the essential to understand what you are asking and define things like fidelity for example.